# Has Many Through. How to get the access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :price_group_lines
has_many :price_groups, through: :price_group_lines

attr_accessible :item_name, :item_id

validates :item_name, presence: true

def to_label
"#{item_name}"
end

end

class PriceGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :customers

has_many :price_group_lines
has_many :items, through: :price_group_lines

attr_accessible :price_group_name

validates :price_group_name, presence: true

def to_label
"#{price_group_name}"
end
end

class PriceGroupLine < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :price_group

attr_accessible :item_id, :price_group_id, :price, :item, :price_group

validates :price, :item_id, :price_group_id, presence: true

end
```

---

View (show.html.erb) for Price Group controller

```
<h1> PRICE GROUP </h1>

<p> <%= @pg.price_group_name %> </p> <br>

<% @pg.items.each do |i|%>
<%= i.item_name %>
<% end %>
<br>

<%= link_to "PRICE GROUP List", price_groups_path %>
```

So, I have the access to item_name in show.html.erb, but i don't know how to get the access to "price" attribute in PriceGroupLine model. Something, like
i.items.price not working. Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is because you have association of `price`, better said `prices`.
Your variable `i` is already `item` just call `price_group_lines` on it and you will get association on which you can call `each` and get each `price`.

```
<% @pg.items.each do |i|%>
  <%= i.item_name %> # will display item name
  <% i.price_group_lines.each do |pgl| %>      
     <%= pgl.price %> # will display price
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Got another problem. In table Price_Group_Lines i have a lot of lines, which have the same item_id, but different price_group_id. When I try to show all price_group_lines in some price_group, I have many price_group_lines with same price_group_id. And I see all prices for all price group lines with same price_group_id.                  How I can show price_group_line only with concrete price_group_id?  (like in SQL WHERE "price_group_line" = "5")

Comment: So, I changed my show.html.erb to i.price_group_lines.where(price_group_id: @pg.id).take, but in browser i see prices lik this -  #<PriceGroupLine:0x007fcc05e53598>